# Keras Classifier giving absurd accuracy for hand gesture classifcation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I am trying to classify hand gestures with a Keras classifier model. But it is giving absurd accuracy while training, like on very first epoc it gives around 80 % a ccuracy and then jumps to 90 %  and final accuracy which comes after 25 epocs is 98 % . I created my own dataset for training which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1onT10LCM5cEkdYv_H7wv6Or0ErxA4nEd?usp=sharing). The 0 folder in dataset is for blank screen.

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense , Dropout
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

# Step 1 - Building the CNN

# Initializing the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# First convolution layer and pooling
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(310, 310, 1), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Second convolution layer and pooling
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
# input_shape is going to be the pooled feature maps from the previous convolution layer
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Flattening the layers
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Adding a fully connected layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.40))
classifier.add(Dense(units=96, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.40))
classifier.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=27, activation='softmax')) # softmax for more than 2

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) # categorical_crossentropy for more than 2


# Step 2 - Preparing the train/test data and training the model

# Code copied from - https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train',
                                                 target_size=(310, 310),
                                                 batch_size=10,
                                                 color_mode='grayscale',
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test',
                                            target_size=(310 , 310),
                                            batch_size=10,
                                            color_mode='grayscale',
                                            class_mode='categorical') 


classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=12841,#9603, # No of images in training set
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=4268)#2580)# No of images in test set


# Saving the model
model_json = classifier.to_json()
with open("model-bw.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
classifier.save_weights('model-bw.h5')
```

When I actually test it using the following code it doesn't shows correct output, like for blan symbol it doesn't shows blank and for all other symbol its hows blank.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import model_from_json
from image_processing import func
import operator
import time 
import cv2
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading the model
minValue = 70
json_file = open("model-bw.json", "r")
model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(model_json)
# load weights into new model
#loaded model = load_model('model-bw.h5')
loaded_model.load_weights("model-bw.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Category dictionary
categories = {0: 'ZERO', 1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO', 3: 'THREE', 4: 'FOUR', 5: 'FIVE'}

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # Simulating mirror image
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    #frame = (cv2.imread("/home/rc/Downloads/soe/train/A/001.jpg"))
    # Got this from collect-data.py
    # Coordinates of the ROI
    x1 = int(0.5*frame.shape[1])
    y1 = 10
    x2 = frame.shape[1]-10
    y2 = int(0.5*frame.shape[1])
    # x1 = 220
    # x2 = 620
    # y1 = 10
    # y2 = 310
    print(x1 , y1 , x2 , y2)
    # Drawing the ROI
    # The increment/decrement by 1 is to compensate for the bounding box
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1-1, y1-1), (x2+1, y2+1), (255,0,0) ,1)
    # Extracting the ROI
    roi = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    # Resizing the ROI so it can be fed to the model for prediction
    #roi = cv2.resize(roi, (64, 64)) 
    #roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #_, test_image = cv2.threshold(roi, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),2)
    # #blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(roi,9,75,75)

    th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
    ret, test_image = cv2.threshold(th3, minValue, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    #time.sleep(5)
    #cv2.imwrite("/home/rc/Downloads/soe/im1.jpg", roi)
    #test_image = func("/home/rc/Downloads/soe/im1.jpg")



    test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (310,310))
    cv2.imshow("test", test_image)
    # Batch of 1
    # print(test_image.reshape(1, 64, 64, 1))
    # break
    result = loaded_model.predict(test_image.reshape(1, 310, 310, 1))
    prediction = {
                  'blank': result[0][0],
                  'A': result[0][1], 
                  'B': result[0][2], 
                  'C': result[0][3],
                  'D': result[0][4],
                  'E': result[0][5],
                  'F': result[0][6],
                  'G': result[0][7],
                  'H': result[0][8],
                  'I': result[0][9],
                  'J': result[0][10],
                  'K': result[0][11],
                  'L': result[0][12],
                  'M': result[0][13],
                  'N': result[0][14],
                  'O': result[0][15],
                  'P': result[0][16],
                  'Q': result[0][17],
                  'R': result[0][18],
                  'S': result[0][19],
                  'T': result[0][20],
                  'U': result[0][21],
                  'V': result[0][22],
                  'W': result[0][23],
                  'X': result[0][24],
                  'Y': result[0][25],
                  'Z': result[0][26],
                }
    # Sorting based on top prediction
    prediction = sorted(prediction.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    # Displaying the predictions
    cv2.putText(frame, prediction[0][0], (10, 120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,255,255), 1)  
    # print(prediction)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    interrupt = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if interrupt & 0xFF == 27: # esc key
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I trained with the same model with another dataset i have which doesn't have blank symbols and only has 24 letters. It used to get trained properly with accuracy in 1st epoch being started from 50% and it used to gradually increase. Input Size we kept in it was 300*300. But it could detect only 13-15 symbols correctly. Not more than that. So i made my own larger dataset(That dataset hadonly 4000 total images and mine has 17000) and kept size as 310*310 and its behaving in an absurd way.If anyone could point out the the mistake, it would be really helpfull

Comment: can you post the output of your training? what is the ratio between your training accuracy and your validation accuracy? it's possible that with only 10k images that you're training over 25 epochs your model is overfit

Comment: training accuracy reached  1 and validation accuracy was around 98.5

Comment: I assume the inputs are images?